# Suspicious Gmail login - by Google ??

Tags: gmail, google, login

I received a "Suspicious sign in prevented" email this morning for one of my Gmail accounts. I changed my password just in case but upon inspecting the email details it looks odd.

It was accessed by `209.85.223.131` which seems to be owned by Google (mail-ie0-f131.google.com). When opening up account activity I get 'Unknown' under access type. So it hasn't even logged whether it was accessed by a browser or by POP.

This all seems very strange. Should I be worried?

Comment: Do you have any Google Scripts which access your Gmail?

Comment: No. I do have another gmail account scraping it's pop3 tho.

Comment: How do you know that IP address belongs to Google?

Comment: @LuketheGeek reverse DNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any suspicious alert should be reviewed carefully. Other users could try to access to your account from other Gmail accounts. If you didn't enabled two step verification (2SV) yet, do it now.

From [About 2-Step Verification - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744?hl=en)

> **Why you should use 2-Step Verification**
>   2-Step Verification adds an extra layer of security to your Google Account, drastically
>   reducing the chances of having the personal information in your
>   account stolen. To break into an account with 2-Step Verification, bad
>   guys would not only have to know your username and password, they'd
>   also have to get a hold of your phone.

The above article includes a step by step guide to enable 2SV.

**References**
[Last account activity - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=45938)
[Detecting suspicious account activity - Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/03/detecting-suspicious-account-activity.html)